# Navigate to nth page in pagination with Selenium (Python) without clicking on every page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Do you guys know a way I could go the nth page (e.g. page 100) in this websites pagination without going through each and every page?

Here is the link to the website: https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings

(Note: Just an example, I am not collecting or selling this data)

I could also do it manually through chrome if there is a way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all data from pages into pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sustainalytics.com/sustapi/companyratings/getcompanyratings"

data = {
    "industry": "",
    "rating": "",
    "filter": "",
    "page": "1",
    "pageSize": "10",
    "resourcePackage": "Sustainalytics",
}

all_rows = []
for data["page"] in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase the range here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, "html.parser")
    for s in soup.select(".company-row"):
        all_rows.append(s.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").split("\n"))
        all_rows[-1].append(
            "https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating" + s.a["data-href"]
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_rows, columns=["Name", "Symbol", "ESG Risk Rating", "Text", "Link"]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                     Name      Symbol ESG Risk Rating             Text                                                                                    Link
0                   1-800-Flowers.com Inc    NAS:FLWS            22.1  Medium ESG Risk              https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/1-800-flowers-com-inc/1007902331
1                                  1&1 AG     ETR:1U1            22.3  Medium ESG Risk                             https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/1-1-ag/1264207944
2                      10X Genomics, Inc.     NAS:TXG            22.6  Medium ESG Risk                   https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/10x-genomics-inc/2000259050
3                               111, Inc.      NAS:YI            28.7  Medium ESG Risk                            https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/111-inc/2006341104
4   17 Education & Technology Group, Inc.      NAS:YQ            27.0  Medium ESG Risk  https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/17-education-technology-group-inc/2008366023
5                  1Life Healthcare, Inc.    NAS:ONEM            24.6  Medium ESG Risk               https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/1life-healthcare-inc/2000165824
6                         1st Source Corp    NAS:SRCE            31.7    High ESG Risk                    https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/1st-source-corp/1008054650
7                       1stdibs.com, Inc.    NAS:DIBS            28.0  Medium ESG Risk                    https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/1stdibs-com-inc/2001638549
8                  22nd Century Group Inc    NAS:XXII            31.7    High ESG Risk             https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/22nd-century-group-inc/1032256453
9                         2i Rete Gas SpA           -            35.3    High ESG Risk                    https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/2i-rete-gas-spa/1008505575
10                               2U, Inc.    NAS:TWOU            19.8     Low ESG Risk                             https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/2u-inc/1068292762
11                     360 DigiTech, Inc.    NAS:QFIN            28.8  Medium ESG Risk                   https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/360-digitech-inc/2006584641
12          360 Security Technology, Inc.  SHG:601360            19.7     Low ESG Risk        https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/360-security-technology-inc/2005880516
13         361 Degrees International Ltd.    HKG:1361            19.1     Low ESG Risk      https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/361-degrees-international-ltd/1068063178
14                       3D Systems Corp.     NYS:DDD            25.8  Medium ESG Risk                    https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3d-systems-corp/1008186648
15                           3i Group PLC     LON:III            11.6     Low ESG Risk                       https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3i-group-plc/1007896757
16                                  3M Co     NYS:MMM            33.6    High ESG Risk                              https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3m-co/1008167440
17                          3M India Ltd.  BOM:523395            23.8  Medium ESG Risk                       https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3m-india-ltd/1008759597
18             3R Petroleum Óleo e Gás SA   BSP:RRRP3            56.0  Severe ESG Risk          https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3r-petroleum-leo-e-g-s-sa/2008351136
19                              3SBio Inc    HKG:1530            27.1  Medium ESG Risk                          https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-rating/3sbio-inc/1032042837
```

---

EDIT: Added "Link" column to dataframe.

Comment: That is a lovely example of a quick scrape. However as I understand it you are scrapping the data without clicking on the each company. I cant do that because I need additional data like "country" which is only shown when clicking on a specific company. Therefore, do you think there is a way to get that additional data with your method? Currently my code clicks on every page and collects the data, but it seems to crash in the further pages like 200, so if you know a way of how I could skip those pages that would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkasPovilaika I've added "Link" column to dataframe. As next step, you could iterate this column, open the link, grab required data and update the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks that will solve my problem, thanks for the intro to bs4.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this, with requests/BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    'industry': '',
    'rating': '',
    'filter': '',
    'page': 100, ### this is where you would select the specific page
    'pageSize': 100,
    'resourcePackage': 'Sustainalytics'
}

r = requests.post('https://www.sustainalytics.com/sustapi/companyratings/getcompanyratings', data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text(strip=True))
```

This would return the text response of that actual table (which is not a table per se, you would need to further isolate and select elements from html response - see the elegant response from Andrej):

```
Sera Prognostics, Inc.NAS:SERA23.9Medium ESG RiskSerba Dinamik Holdings Bhd.KLS:527944.6Severe ESG RiskSerco Group PLCLON:SRP19.1Low ESG RiskSercomm Corp.TAI:538824.3Medium ESG RiskSeres Therapeutics IncNAS:MCRB35.9High ESG RiskSeria Co. Ltd.TKS:278221.7Medium  [....]
```

And you would do something like this with Selenium (which in itself is not a tool designed to send POST requests, hence it will execute Javascript to get the data and replace the information in page):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings'
browser.get(url)
print('sending xhr request..')

browser.execute_script('''
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.sustainalytics.com/sustapi/companyratings/getcompanyratings',
  data: 'industry=&rating=&filter=&page=100&pageSize=10&resourcePackage=Sustainalytics',
  success: function(data){
      $('#company_ratings').html(data);
  }
});
            
            ''')

print('check page content, xhr response returned')
```

The table in page would be updated with `page 100` information, and pagination would reflect that as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your Selenium method, and it did work, however the page became unusable (couldn't click on any links). Also when my code tried going to the next page the website dropped an error. Also when you refresh the page an error pops out. Do you think there is a work around this? In the meantime ill try using the bs4 method, although i'm not familiar with the library.

Comment: Your question is a bit of an XY Problem. You asked (formally) for a way to navigate to a specific page with Selenium, when in fact you need the data, from page 1 => last page. For that amount of data and this website structure, requests (bs4 is just the html parser) is the way forward.. and I would even suggest looking at some async options, beside requests.